# Is there an open-source javascript calendar that supports built-in event detail popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, calendar

In this google calendar, when you click on a date which has an event, it will popup the event details.

http://examples.tripod.com/calendar.html

This is what I need (though its size is much larger than I need), but after searching on google, I realize there is a big limitation with google calendar. There is no easy way to customize its style using css because embedded google calendar is provided inside an iframe. There are solutions such as [RESTYLEgc](http://www.restylegc.com/) , but I don't really want to go for it.

Now I am looking for an open-source javascript calendar that supports built-in event detail popup. It can be an extremely simple one, as long as it allows year/month navigation and it can highlight the date that has an event on it, and of course the built-in event pop up feature.

It will be great if it's built on jQuery since I already have the jQuery library included on the website.

I have only very few important events to set on the calendar, I expect I will be using codes like these:

```
var event1Html='<div class="event-details">Some event details here</div>';
calendar.setEvent('2012-1-25',event1Html);

var event2Html='<div class="event-details">Some other event details here</div>';
calendar.setEvent('2012-1-31',event2Html);
```

Is there such a javascript calendar that you know of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would look in to the [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) script. From the looks of it, it can bring in google calendars, but also has an `eventClick` event that you can bind to and use (possibly) jQuery-UI to show a dialog of further information.

For a demo, do the following:

1. Visit that fullcalendar site and download the latest version (looks to be 1.5.2)
2. Extract the `fullcalendar-1.5.2\fullcalendar-1.5.2\fullcalendar` folder to your desktop.
3. Create a "calendardemo.html" file on your desktop and paste the following in to it:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calendar Demo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css' media='print' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
      }

      #calendar {
        width: 640px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>



  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
    <div class="ui-helper-hidden" id="calendar-details" title="Event Details">
      <p>Event details</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var $dialog = $('#calendar-details').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          model: true,
          height: 300,
          width: 350
        });

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          editable: true,
          events: [
            {
              title: 'All Day Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
              title: 'Long Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
              end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
              id: 999,
              title: 'Repeating Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
              allDay: false
            },
            {
              id: 999,
              title: 'Repeating Event',
              start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
              allDay: false
            },
            {
              title: 'Meeting',
              start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
              allDay: false
            },
            {
              title: 'Lunch',
              start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
              end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
              allDay: false
            },
            {
              title: 'Birthday Party',
              start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
              end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
              allDay: false
            },
            {
              title: 'Click for Google',
              start: new Date(y, m, 28),
              end: new Date(y, m, 29),
              url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
          ],
          eventClick: function(event,jsEvent,view){
            console.log(event);
            $dialog.dialog({title:event.title});
            $('p',$dialog).empty().append(
              $('<p />').text(event.allDay ? 'All day event' : 'Scheduled: ' + event.start + '-' + event.end)
            );
            $dialog.dialog('open');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now click on an event. Unpolished, yes, but shows a pretty simple way of achieving what you're going for.